# Referencing an array on stage from another movieclip

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, movieclip

I have an array of MovieClips (on the main stages actions) that i want to refer to from within other movieclips placed on the stage.

```
var hotSpots:Array =[hotSpot1, hotSpot2, control_mc, tip_mc]

for each (var removeHotspots:MovieClip in hotSpots)
{
    removeHotspots.visible = false;
}
```

How do i refer back to this array from within another movieclip without having to add the array again?

I tried...

```
var hotSpots:Array = Object(this).hotSpots
```

and then within my event Listener...

```
for each (var removeHotspots:MovieClip in hotSpots)
    {
        removeHotspots.visible = true;
    }
```

But it doesn't seem to work? Can anyone help.
I have alot of arrays like this that i really dont want to have to add to each movieclip everytime i need to call them.

Comment: Try to use `MovieClip(root).hotSpots`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"this" refers to the MovieClip your code is within. If you want to access the parent MovieClip (in this case the root or stage) you can either use `parent.hotSpots` or `stage.hotSpots`. However, this requires the MovieClip to be added to the stage (and thereby the display list), otherwise both `parent` and `stage` will be null.

If you want to wait for a MovieClip to be on stage before executing code where you refer to the `stage` variable you can use the event `Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE`